# PowerShell parameter value suggestions

Tags: c#, powershell

I have written a Cmdlet in C#. Is it possible to provide all possible values for a specific string Parameter ("PackageId" is this sample)?

```
public sealed class InstallPackageCommand : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true)]
    public string PackageId { get; set; }

    protected override void BeginProcessing()
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `ValidateSetAttribute` on your property for that parameter e.g.:

```
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty]
[ValidateSet(new string[] {"a","b","c"})]
[Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true)]
public string PackageId { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is a good idea. My values are only known at runtime but this can be achieved by using the IDynamicParameters interface where the attributes can be set at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custome enum:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/01/23/how-to-create-enum-in-powershell.aspx

and then make your variable that enum type.

This will also make the possible values work with Powershell tab-completion from the command lilne.

Comment: How do I do this in C#? The type of the parameter is still a string, isn't it? The values that should be entered by the user are actually names of directories in the file system on a network share.

Comment: Afraid I don't know C#, I've only done this in PS.  The type will be whatever you call your enum, and that will constrain the value to one of the strings defined in the type.

Answer (score 0):

Custom enum example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace ExampleNameSpace
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Something")]
    [OutputType("PSCustomObject")]
    public class GetSomething : PSCmdlet
    {
        public enum ExampleEnum { A, B, C };

        [Parameter(
            HelpMessage = "Enter A, B, or C.",
            Mandatory = true,
            Position = 0,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true,
            ValueFromPipeline = true
        )]
        public ExampleEnum ExampleParameter { get; set; }

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            WriteObject(ExampleParameter);
            switch (ExampleParameter)
            {
                case ExampleEnum.A:
                    WriteObject("Case A");
                    break;
                case ExampleEnum.B:
                    WriteObject("Case B");
                    break;
                case ExampleEnum.C:
                    WriteObject("Case C");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example #1:

```
$ Get-Something

cmdlet Get-Something at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
ExampleParameter: !?
Enter A, B, or C.
ExampleParameter: a
A
Case A
```

Usage example #2:

```
$ Get-Something -ExampleParameter x
Get-Something : Cannot bind parameter 'ExampleParameter'. Cannot convert value "x" to type
"ExampleNameSpace.GetSomething+ExampleEnum". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name x to a valid enumerator name.
Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again:
A, B, C"
At line:1 char:33
+ Get-Something -ExampleParameter x
+                                 ~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Something], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,ExampleNameSpace.GetSomething
```

Usage example #3:

```
$ "a","b","c","d" | Get-Something
A
Case A
B
Case B
C
Case C
Get-Something : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not
take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:1 char:20
+ "a","b","c","d" | Get-Something
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (d:String) [Get-Something], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,ExampleNameSpace.GetSomething
```