# Confusing for passing multiple enum values from powershell to .NET

Tags: c#, powershell, enums

When I'm try to write cmdlet in c#, which accept the enum type value, and access input from Powershell, and when I get multiple value input from powershell, I get unexpected behavoir...Take the following code as example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace ExampleNameSpace
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Something")]
    [OutputType("PSCustomObject")]
    public class GetSomething : PSCmdlet
    {
        public enum ExampleEnum { A, B, C };

        [Parameter(
            HelpMessage = "Enter A, B, or C.",
            Mandatory = true,
            Position = 0,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true,
            ValueFromPipeline = true
        )]
        public ExampleEnum ExampleParameter { get; set; }

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            WriteObject(ExampleParameter);
            switch (ExampleParameter)
            {
                case ExampleEnum.A:
                    WriteObject("Case A");
                    break;
                case ExampleEnum.B:
                    WriteObject("Case B");
                    break;
                case ExampleEnum.C:
                    WriteObject("Case C");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These code is get from [PowerShell parameter value suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709179/powershell-parameter-value-suggestions)

And when I'm open powershell, input cmdlet like this:

```
Get-Something A, B
```

What I suspect the powershell should return me an error, but powershell write out the value **"Case B"**

When I input cmdlet like this:

```
Get-Something A, C
```

Powershell write out the value **"Case C"**

And When I input cmdlet like this:

```
Get-Something B, C
```

Powershell will return an error says that the value is invalid.

What I expect that the powershell shouldn't get multiple values for the multiple enum parameters(except for

the enums which has [Flag] attribute)

Can anyone tell me what's going on in Powershell? Thanks very much

Comment: Post the entire PS error spew.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to tell precisely what the answer here is without knowing exactly what your PowerShell command even is let alone the precise error message, but this:

```
Get-Something A, C
```

Looks really suspicious.  This is calling `Get-Something` with one argument that is an array of two items: A and C.

However, you said that A and C are Enums, but that's not typically how an Enum works.  Enums are bitmasks.  No matter how many of the flags are set, internally it's represented by a single integer.  That means, for example, that you don't represent Read-Only and Archive being set like this:

```
PS C:\> $ReadOnly = [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly
PS C:\> $Archive = [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Archive
PS C:\> $ReadOnly, $Archive
ReadOnly
Archive
```

You represent it like this:

```
PS C:\> $ReadOnly = [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly
PS C:\> $Archive = [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Archive
PS C:\> $ReadOnly -bor $Archive
ReadOnly, Archive
```

You get one item with both ReadOnly and Archive set.

However, PowerShell is smart enough to parse a string with comma delimited names of an Enum:

```
PS C:\> [System.IO.FileAttributes]'ReadOnly, Archive'
ReadOnly, Archive
```

Comment: Yeah, when I'm try to write ```Get-Something A,C```.  I suspect that the powershell should return an error because ```Get-Something``` here is only accept the enum input.  But powershell can pass it to the .NET code, and when I debug the .NET code, it seems that parameter ```ExampleParameter``` value is ```C```.  It make me so confuse.   Typically, the cmdlet like ```Get-Something``` here should accept only one enum value with type ```ExampleEnum```, but it's not work as I expect..

Answer (score 0):

Realizing this is an old question, this question is (at time of writing) the second Google result for "powershell parameter enum without flags" and while the previous example explains *why* this happens it doesn't explain how to prevent it.

As per the answer by BaconBits, PowerShell implicitly converts strings into types derived from `System.Enum` by parsing the string, and converts `object[]` arrays into `System.Enum` by bitmask (C#'s `|` operator, in PowerShell called  as `-bor`). This conversion is implicit in any situation where you try to convert one string into an enum, multiple strings into an enum, or multiple enums into an enum of the same type.

Unfortunately, PowerShell will do this even when the `enum` type does not have the `Flags` attribute. To override this behavior when parsing a parameter value, you'll need to use an attribute derived from `System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTransformationAttribute` such as the following example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace ExampleNamespace
{
    // note that you can't derive from ValidateArgumentsAttribute as you need to catch the value
    // before it has been converted. ArgumentTransformationAttributes are applied before the
    // implicit PowerShell type casting system, which is applied before parameter validation,
    // and are permitted to throw ArgumentException if the argument is invalid.
    public class ValidateFlaglessEnumAttribute : ArgumentTransformationAttribute
    {
        public override object Transform(EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics, object inputData)
        {
            // PowerShell will generally use object[], but if the parameter value is provided
            // by a property of an object we may have some other enumerable type
            if (inputData is IEnumerable enumerable) 
            {
                // basically any enumeration indicates we weren't passed a single enum value
                // however, as we could have a collection, we'll verify that there's more
                // than one value before throwing.
                var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
                try
                {
                    enumerator.MoveNext(); // move to the first value
                    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        throw new PSArgumentException("The value provided must be a " +
                        "single enumeration value (flags and arrays are not supported).");
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    (enumerator as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
                }
            }
            // if we pass out the object that was passed in, PowerShell will still
            // apply the default type casting to the object - so if we were given a
            // string, we can return that string and PowerShell will convert it to
            // the enum we asked for in our cmdlet.
            return inputData;
        }
    }
}
```

This attribute can be put on a parameter in a script function or cmdlet:

```
public enum Letter
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}
public class MyCmdlet : Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter]
    [ExampleNamespace.ValidateFlaglessEnum]
    public Letter Letter {get; set;}
[...]
```

```
enum Letter {
    A
    B
    C
}
function My-Function {
    [CmldetBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [ExampleNamespace.ValidateFlaglessEnum()]
        [Letter]$Letter
[...]
```

These will result in an error preventing the command from being invoked if called with multiple values for the `Letter` parameter:

```
My-Function : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Letter'. The value provided must be a single enumeration value (the parameter does not support flags).
At line:1 char:21
+ My-Function -letter a,b | out-string|scb
+                     ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [My-Function], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,My-Function
```

Note that the `[Flags]` attribute isn't significant to this validation either, and you'll need to explicitly decorate each parameter that you don't want to accept flags from with this attribute.